# Key Error 22, get Loc error appear when i want to remove row content with datetime format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, error-handling, data-cleaning

In my data, there are rows which are system generated and not related to the data hence i want to remove it.

Sample data

```
name | num of books
Yuzu | 5
Apple | 6
Orange | 7
Total Records: 3
Generating Start At: Thu Feb 4 16:09:54 2021
Generating End at : Thu Feb 4 16:10:01 2021
```

Based on the sample data, i will remove the last 3 rows. As the rows doesnt not always appear, i will need to have some checks before removing the rows.

My codes:

```
listOfCol = list(df.columns.values)
colOne = listOfCol[0]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  columnValue = df.loc[index, colOne]
  if ("Generating" in columnValue or "Total Records" in columnValue):
      df = df.drop(df.index[index])

print(df)
```

The codes was able to remove "Total Records: 3" but an error was thrown when it reached the second data row.

KeyError: 22, Related to get_col/ get_item on line > columnValue = df.loc[index, colOne]

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dropping df while iterating over it, this might lead to some unexpected behavior. You can store a index list while iterating and drop the index in list after iteration.

```py
listOfCol = list(df.columns.values)
colOne = listOfCol[0]
indexToDropList = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  columnValue = df.loc[index, colOne]
  if ("Generating" in columnValue or "Total Records" in columnValue):
      indexToDropList.append(index)

df = df.drop(df.index[indexToDropList])
print(df)
```

You can implement the same effect with

```py
df = df[~df['col'].str.contains('|'.join(['Generating', 'Total Records']))]
```